# firestore paginations error: order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Firestore gives an error when trying to paginate the query using `start_after`.

A short excerpt from my code:

```
query = USER_COLLECTION.where("status", "==", "active")
query = query.where("favFruits", "in", ["mango", "orange"])
query = query.order_by("name", "DESCENDING")
```

If I do `query.get()` at this point, it gives me valid results but the below step fails

```
query = query.start_after(USER_COLLECTION.document(last_processed_document_id).get())
```

calling `.get()` on the above `query` is gives an error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter favFruits
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample query that you provided, this is a part of the limitation of ordering and limiting data with Cloud Firestore.

According to [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations):

> - An `orderBy()` clause also filters for existence of the given fields. The result set will not include documents that do not contain the given fields.
> - If you include a filter with a range comparison (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`), your first ordering must be on the same field.
> - You cannot order your query by any field included in an equality (`=`) or `in` clause.

Meaning your query should appear like this:

```
query = query.where("favFruits", "in", ["mango", "orange"])
query = query.order_by("favFruits", "DESCENDING")
```